# MariaDB JSON Query

Tags: json, mariadb

I have a table with the following structure:

```
|id | json |
------------
|   |      |
------------
```

The JSON structure is as follows:

```
{
    "roomType": "Deluxe",
    "package": "Full-Board +",
    "comb": {
        "adult": "1",
        "infant": "0",
        "child": "0",
        "teen": "0"
    },
    "rates": [
    {
        "rateFrom": "2021-02-11",
        "rateTo": "2021-02-20",
        "ratePrice": "6000"
    }, {
        "rateFrom": "2021-02-21",
        "rateTo": "2021-02-26",
        "ratePrice": "6500"
    }]
}
```

There can be many entries in attribute `rates`.
Now, I need to return the rows where any of the attribute `rateTo` from `rates` is greater than today's date.

That is, if today's date is less than **at least one `rateTo`** of the entries of `rates`, then return that row.

This is the first time I am querying JSON and I am not sure if the structure of my JSON is correct for the type of querying I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be *much* easier if you abandoned JSON as a datatype and used properly normalised tables of rooms, packages, comb (might be part of packages?) and rates. If you are stuck with JSON though, one way to get the data you want is to extract all the `rateTo` values from each JSON into a comma separated (and ended) list of dates (for example, for your sample data, this would be `2021-02-20,2021-02-26,`; then split that into individual dates `2021-02-20` and `2021-02-26`, then `SELECT` rows from the original table if one of the associated dates is after today. You can do this with a couple of recursive CTEs:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE toDate AS (
  SELECT id, CONCAT(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(`json`, '$.rates[*].rateTo'), '[ "\\[\\]]', ''), ',') AS toDates
  FROM rooms
),
Dates AS (
  SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(toDates, ',', 1) AS toDate, REGEXP_REPLACE(toDates, '^[^,]+,', '') AS balance
  FROM toDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(balance, ',', 1), REGEXP_REPLACE(balance, '^[^,]+,', '')
  FROM Dates
  WHERE INSTR(balance, ',') > 0
)
SELECT *
FROM rooms r
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM Dates d
              WHERE d.id = r.id AND d.toDate > CURDATE())
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=66061f5e9173597272b4093c0251dcb0)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with JSON but your solution worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @jo12345678 sorry to hear about the JSON, but I'm glad this worked for you.